CNG, Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider, and the "Invalid provider type specified" error
Recently, our enterprise began issuing new CNG server certificates.  We just installed the first of these on an app server, and it seems to have broken a web services call with the error "Invalid provider type specified".
In examining the PKS file, the provider appears to be "Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider".
If I import the cert into the local key store, but override the CSP to "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", it works fine, but ideally, I would like the app to work without overriding the CSP.
I am guessing that the core issue is in this snippet of code:
var store2 = X509CertificateStore.LocalMachineStore(X509CertificateStore.MyStore);
store2.OpenRead();

var coll2 = store2.FindCertificateBySubjectString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["<redacted>"]);

if (coll2.Count > 0)
{
//var cert2    = new X509Certificate2(coll2[0]);
  var cert2    = coll2[0];
  var certType = cert2.GetType();
  var cert3    = new X509Certificate2(cert2);
  certType     = cert3.GetType();

  if (cert2.SupportsDigitalSignature)
  {
    svc.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(cert2);
  }
}

As best I can tell, the code is looking for certificate(s) that match the local servers name (i.e. appserver.fqdn.com) in the Local Cert Store (coll2), creating a new object from that raw data (cert2) and recasting it as an X509Certificate2 object.  It then sets the Certificate attribute/tag in the web service's ClientCredentials / ClientCertificate / Certificate attribute.  I am guessing there is something subtle about CNG that is not working here, but I am uncertain how to update the code to properly pass the identity certificate to the web services call.
If I import the certificate into the local certificate store, but override the CSP, ("certutil.exe -csp "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -importpfx <certificate file>"), the code works as expected, but I would like to update the code to work without this admin step.

"CNG server certificates" - what do you mean by this? There's nothing inherently "CNG" about a certificate - CNG is just an API for using certificates; with limited exceptions you could use any other API like CAPI/CryptoAPI or OpenSSL too.

That's what the Admins told me.  It may be wholly irrelevant to my issue, (and only relevant in that the CNG API was needed to generate the certificate in a PFX file).
